# Uploading project files into different folders in Netbeans IDE

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

How can i upload project files in different folders?

I've created a project with 2 folders called "netbeans" and "smarty/templates". Now I would like to upload:

- "netbeans" into /var/www/htdocs
- "smarty/templates" into /var/www/smarty/templates

AND - that's the tricky part - keep http://< server >/netbeans/ as project url.
So i can't add some folders in order to build a project folder structure like "www/htdocs/netbeans" and "www/smarty/templates", that would change the url.

Environment:

- NetBeans IDE 7.3

Comment: Look at url rewriting, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: that is a "solution" like: upload it manually, use 2 projects, use inotify, eclipse is able to do that, ...